# Android Layout: My images are filling only about 2/3 of my screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have a new Activity with related layout which works fine.
Except the ImageView(s) don't cover the whole width of my screen.

I'm using Android Studio (the latest stable version) and surprisingly inside the IDE the preview of my layout looks fine. But when I run the app on my device (or emulator) it doesn't cover the whole screen.

Here is my layout design:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cat_food"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cat_food" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cat_drink"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cat_drink" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cat_coffee"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cat_coffee" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cat_shopping"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cat_shopping" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cat_offers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/cat_offers" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<include
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"
    layout="@layout/layout_actionbar" />
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you for your help.

P.S.
I tried wrap_contents, match_parent, fill_parent already and none of those solved the problem.

Comment: set it as a background and make width match parent

Comment: I did and still have problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the ImageView width to `fill_parent` or `match_parent` and additionally use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` I've tested this and the ImageView is filling the whole width of the screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cat_food"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_logo" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cat_drink"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_logo" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cat_coffee"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_logo" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cat_shopping"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_logo" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cat_offers"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_logo" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <include
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"
    layout="@layout/layout_actionbar" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It solved the width problem, but now the height is the issue. It seems that images are stretched to cover the width... in other word the height are not grown proportionately. Any idea why is that?

Comment: There might be an issue with your Image size. Make sure they are not square shaped like 100*100 and they have a sufficient wide shape to fill the background e.g 250*100.

Comment: Well they are in 3 different sizes. For example I have them in 720x266 for drawable-hdpi and 360x133 for drawable-mdpi

Comment: did you tried by removing android:adjustViewBounds="true" and android:scaleType="fitXY" ?

Comment: Yes I did...actually I tried every single combination that I could think about... still I get the stretched image (width filled fully but the height is shorter than it should be) Thanks for your help anyways.
p.s. hope those loosers who gave minus to this question realize that there is someone who needs help and already tried all similar answers. As I said before the preview in Android Studio is totally fine but in the emulators or devices I got different results.Please understand it is not even similar to other questions.You might to pay attention to details before give negative to a question